# Filtering array based on selected checkboxes and select fields

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

How can I store the selected values of checkboxes and select elements and use a combination of these to filter a results array? e.g. think filtering by category Id, or displaying all results in the last X months.

After much research and trial and error I've got as far as this:

View **[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/XnFxeLQbiJRGBkIwKaGr?p=preview)** or see the code below:

**HTML within the 'refine' directive**

```
<div class="filters">
    <div class="filter">
        <label for="maxage">Show results from</label>
        <select name="maxage" id="maxage" 
                ng-options="option.name for option in refine.maxAge.options track by option.id" 
                ng-model="refine.maxAge.selected"
                ng-change="filterResults()">
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="filter">
        <div class="status-filter" ng-repeat="status in refine.statuses">
            <label for="statusId{{ status.id }}">{{ status.name }}</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="status" value="{{ status.id }}" ng-change="filterResults()">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**HTML of main page**

```
<body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="ListCtrl" data-county-parish-id="1478">
        ...
            <main class="page-content columns medium-9 medium-push-3">
                    ...
                    <spinner name="planningSpinner" show="true">
                        <div class="loadingPanel block"></div>
                    </spinner>

                    <div class="planning">
                        <div class="no-results ng-hide" ng-show="filteredResults.length === 0">
                            <p>No results.</p>
                        </div>
                        <h4>Number of records: {{ filteredResults.length }}</h4>
                        <div ng-repeat="appl in filteredResults">
                            <hf-application info="appl"></hf-application>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    ...
            </main>
            <aside class="sidebar columns medium-3 medium-pull-9">
                ...
                <div hf-refine-results info="refine"></div>
            </aside>
        ...
    </div>
</body>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

// results filter
angular.module('app').filter('results', ['$filter', function($filter) {
    return function (input, refine) {
        var filterParams = {};
        // start off filtering with the outsideBoundary parameter
        filterParams.outsideBoundary = refine.outsideBoundary;

        // add 'show results from' filter
        //var adjustedDate = new Date();
        //adjustedDate.setMonth(adjustedDate.getMonth() - refine.maxAge.selected.id);
        //filterParams.receivedDate = $filter('date')(adjustedDate, 'yyyy/MM/dd');

        return $filter('filter')(input, filterParams);
    }
}]);

// Controller
angular.module('app').controller('ListCtrl',
        ['$scope', '$filter', '$attrs', 'appService', 'resultsFilter', function ($scope, $filter, $attrs, appService, resultsFilter) {

    $scope.applications = [];
    $scope.refine = {
        statuses: {
            options: [
                { id: 1, name: 'Unknown' },
                ...
                { id: 6, name: 'Appealed' }
            ],
            selected: [2, 3]
        },
        maxAge: {
            options: [
                { id: '1', name: 'Last month' },
                ... // 1 to 12 months
                { id: '12', name: 'Last 12 months' }
            ],
            selected: { id: '6', name: 'Last 6 months' }
        },
        ...
    };

    $scope.filterResults = function () {
        $scope.filteredResults = resultsFilter($scope.applications, $scope.refine);
    };

    /* get data from appService */
    appService.getApplications({
        status: 3,
        countyparish: parseInt($attrs.countyParishId),
        postcode: '',
        distance: 5,
        pagesize: 100
    })
    .then(function (data) {
        $scope.applications = data;
        $scope.filteredResults = resultsFilter(data, $scope.refine);
    });
}]);
```

I appreciate this question has been asked many times, however I haven't found an answer for my question(s) since most examples are very simple expressions within ng-repeat.

Comment: Whats is resultsFilter?

Comment: It's the 'results' filter at the top of the JS snippet. As per AngularJS [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter): _"You can also use filters in controllers, services, and directives. For this, inject a dependency with the name <filterName>Filter to your controller/service/directive. E.g. using the dependency numberFilter will inject the number filter"_

Comment: Post code this please!

Comment: The code is there? The 'results' filter starts with this line `angular.module('app').filter('results', ...` which is injected as `resultsFilter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example work with multi checkbox. For filtering with outher select use same logic. Look

```js
'use strict';
var App = angular.module('clientApp', ['ngResource', 'App.filters']);
App.controller('ClientCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.selectedCompany = [];
    $scope.companyList = [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'Apple'
    }, {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Facebook'
    }, {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Google'
    }];

    $scope.clients = [{
        name: 'Brett',
        designation: 'Software Engineer',
        company: {
            id: 1,
            name: 'Apple'
        }
    }, {
        name: 'Steven',
        designation: 'Database Administrator',
        company: {
            id: 3,
            name: 'Google'
        }
    }, {
        name: 'Jim',
        designation: 'Designer',
        company: {
            id: 2,
            name: 'Facebook'
        }
    }, {
        name: 'Michael',
        designation: 'Front-End Developer',
        company: {
            id: 1,
            name: 'Apple'
        }
    }, {
        name: 'Josh',
        designation: 'Network Engineer',
        company: {
            id: 3,
            name: 'Google'
        }
    }, {
        name: 'Ellie',
        designation: 'Internet Marketing Engineer',
        company: {
            id: 1,
            name: 'Apple'
        }
    }];

    $scope.setSelectedClient = function () {
        var id = this.company.id;
        if (_.contains($scope.selectedCompany, id)) {
            $scope.selectedCompany = _.without($scope.selectedCompany, id);
        } else {
            $scope.selectedCompany.push(id);
        }
        return false;
    };

    $scope.isChecked = function (id) {
        if (_.contains($scope.selectedCompany, id)) {
            return 'icon-ok pull-right';
        }
        return false;
    };

    $scope.checkAll = function () {
        $scope.selectedCompany = _.pluck($scope.companyList, 'id');
    };
}]);

angular.module('App.filters', []).filter('companyFilter', [function () {
    return function (clients, selectedCompany) {
        if (!angular.isUndefined(clients) && !angular.isUndefined(selectedCompany) && selectedCompany.length > 0) {
            var tempClients = [];
            angular.forEach(selectedCompany, function (id) {
                angular.forEach(clients, function (client) {
                    if (angular.equals(client.company.id, id)) {
                        tempClients.push(client);
                    }
                });
            });
            return tempClients;
        } else {
            return clients;
        }
    };
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.4.4/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.0/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css">


<div ng-app="clientApp" data-ng-controller="ClientCtrl">
    <ul class="inline">
        <li>
            <div class="alert alert-info">
                 <h4>Total Filtered Client: {{filtered.length}}</h4>

            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="btn-group" data-ng-class="{open: open}">
                <button class="btn">Filter by Company</button>
                <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-ng-click="open=!open"><span class="caret"></span>

                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
                    <li><a data-ng-click="checkAll()"><i class="icon-ok-sign"></i>  Check All</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a data-ng-click="selectedCompany=[];"><i class="icon-remove-sign"></i>  Uncheck All</a>

                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li data-ng-repeat="company in companyList"> <a data-ng-click="setSelectedClient()">{{company.name}}<span data-ng-class="isChecked(company.id)"></span></a>

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <hr/>
     <h3>Clients Table:</h3>

    <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="width:10%">#</th>
                <th style="width:20%">Name</th>
                <th style="width:40%">Designation</th>
                <th style="width:30%">Company</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr data-ng-repeat="client in filtered = (clients | companyFilter:selectedCompany)">
                <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
                <td><em>{{client.name}}</em>

                </td>
                <td>{{client.designation}}</td>
                <td>{{client.company.name}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Although you didn't use my code in your example, there was enough in there to see where I was going wrong and I now have my code working - thanks.